# Plotting a nested multi box plots with Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, seaborn, boxplot

I would like to create a plot similar to the attached one with my own data. I would like to input the data manually instead of importing it. Similar to the attached, I would like to replace "Lunch" with "Classe1" and "Dinner" with "Classe2", remove the label "Time" and replace "day = X" by "Groupe=A or B..". My code is as below. Thanks in advance for help.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.set(style="ticks", palette='Set2', font='Roboto Condensed')
sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=1.1, rc={"lines.linewidth": 1.1})
g=sns.factorplot(x="time", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
           col="day", data=tips, kind="box", size=4, aspect=0.5,
             width=0.8,fliersize=2.5,linewidth=1.1, notch=False,orient="v")
sns.despine(trim=True)
g.savefig('test6.png', format='png', dpi=600)
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide mockup data, in particular check out [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)